# Leer y Editar Base de Datos en la Tarjeta SD Card externa con ORMLite

Tags: android, base-de-datos, orm, almacenamiento

Estoy tratando de averiguar cómo poder usar una base de datos que esté ubicada en el almacenamiento externo del dispositivo, es decir en la micro SD. He leído mucho buscando la respuesta a mi pregunta pero en todos los casos las soluciones que se proponen es para usar la base de datos desde el SD Card interno pero no en el almacenamiento externo. Lo que quiero lograr es poder leer y editar una base de datos de gran tamaño que está almacenada en la tarjeta SD. He aquí la importancia de que se pueda hacer esto desde la tarjeta de memoria externa en el caso de los dispositivos que sí la tengan. Agradecería cualquier ayuda.

Editando:
Lo que necesito hacer es algo como esto pero con la clase extendida de `ORMLiteSQLOpenHelper`

```
SQLiteDatabase sqlite = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(
    "/storage/extSdCard/test.db",
    null,
    SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE | SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS);
```

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, agrega lo que has investigado o intentado, agrega tu còdigo, revisa [ask] y edita tu pregunta, saludos.

Comment: En que lenguaje? y que codigo realizaste?

Comment: Estoy usando Java con Android Studio